# Attempting to change the colour for alternative lines in a table using CSS for a PHP script

Tags: php, html, css, tags

Attempting to change the colour for alternative lines in a table using CSS for a PHP script. I have got the colour but the lines are repeating in my script. Is there anyway around this?

The PHP Script:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers()); 

$config['db'] = array( //This is the config array with the database details
    'host'              => 'localhost',
    'username'          => 'root',
    'password'          => '',
    'dbname'            => 'website'
); 


//echo '<table, th, td {border: 2px solid black; border-collapse="collapse";} >';
echo '<table id="customers"}>';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">';

echo '<th> one </th>';
echo '<th> two </th>';
echo '<th> three </th>';
echo '<th> four </th>';


$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']); //Instanciate an PDO Object


$query = $db->query("SELECT `articles`.`title`, `articles`.`hello`, `articles`.`id`,         `articles`.`name` FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`title` > 1 LIMIT 5");//running a query         from the database


while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>';
echo $row["title"];
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo $row["hello"];
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo $row["id"];
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo $row["name"];
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr class="alt">';
echo '<td>';
echo $row["title"];
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo $row["hello"];
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo $row["id"];
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo $row["name"];
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';

//print_r($query); //printing a query 

};

echo '</table>';

echo '<p> Returned ', $query->rowCount(), ' results due to limit set</p>';


//$query = $db->query("SELECT `title` FROM `articles`");//running a query from the database


//$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM articles");


//print_r($query); //printing a query

//$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
//$stmt->execute();
//$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

/* $query = $db->query("SELECT `id` FROM `articles`");//running a query from the database

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo $row['title'], '<br>';
echo $row['id'], '<br>';
}

}

*/
```

The CSS Script:

```
#customers
{
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
width:100%;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
#customers td, #customers th 
{
font-size:1.2em;
border:1px solid #98bf21;
padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;
}
#customers th 
{
font-size:1.4em;
text-align:left;
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:4px;
background-color:#A7C942;
color:#fff;
}
#customers tr.alt td 
{
color:#000;
background-color:#EAF2D3;
}
```

Comment: Side note - you should be HTML encoding your output to prevent an XSS attack.

Comment: Any good resources that I would need to look in to?

Comment: My knowledge of PHP is limited, but there appears to be a function `htmlentities` that you can use to HTML encode strings - http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$alt=0;
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
 if($alt==0){
  echo '<tr>';
  $alt=1;
 }else{
  echo '<tr class="alt">';
  $alt=0;
 }
 echo '<td>';
 echo $row["title"];
 echo '</td>';
 echo '<td>';
 echo $row["hello"];
 echo '</td>';
 echo '<td>';
 echo $row["id"];
 echo '</td>';
 echo '<td>';
 echo $row["name"];
 echo '</td>';
 echo '</tr>';
}
```

Don't repeat rows twice inside your while loop. Just do it once and alternate the class assignment.

Comment: What is the best way to do this? I'm thinking its going to be if odd, do this if even do this? But not sure of the implementation. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: mmm well it's nothing special. The $alt variable alternates between the 0 and 1 values at every cycle of the while loop. When its value is 0 just adds <tr>, when it's 1 it adds <tr class="alt">. If you replace your while loop code with mine it should work as you wanted.

Comment: this is oldest way. you have to use css3. It is latest, easy, fast and better.

Answer (score 2):

here is **ccs3**  *:)*

try it

```
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #555555;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Or with class

```
<table class='demo'>
<tr><td>hi</td></tr>
<tr><td>hi</td></tr>
<tr><td>hi</td></tr>
<tr><td>hi</td></tr>
<table>

.demo tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #555555;
}

.demo tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give each second row a specific css class, and move on, or look into jquery zebra table.

Here is a tutorial http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Zebra_Striping_Made_Easy

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this

```
$count = 0;
while(/*statement here */) {

  if($count%2 == 0){

    $class= "odd";

  } else{

    $class = "normal";

  }

 echo "<tr class=\"$class\"></tr>";

 $count++;
}
```